# java windows desktop mail subject string error

Tags: java, windows, email, outlook

I want to send an email through java.
The code is:

```
ueberschrift = table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
text = table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();

ueberschrift = ueberschrift.replace(" ", "%20")
        .replace("\n", "%0D%0A").replace("\"", "\u00A8")
        .replace("%", "%25").replace(";", "%3B")
        .replace("?", "%3F").replace("&", "%24")
        .replace("$", "%26").replace("<", "%3C")
        .replace(">", "%3E").replace("~", "%7E")
        .replace("\\", "\u00A8");
text = text.replace(" ", "%20").replace("\n", "%0D%0A")
        .replace("\"", "\u00A8").replace("%", "%25")
        .replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F")
        .replace("&", "%24").replace("$", "%26")
        .replace("<", "%3C").replace(">", "%3E")
        .replace("~", "%7E").replace("\\", "\u00A8");
System.out.println(text);
if (anrede.equals("Frau")) {
    einleitung = "Sehr%20geehrte%20";
} else {
    einleitung = "Sehr%20geehrter%20";
}

text = einleitung
        + anrede
        + "%20"
        + name
        + ",%20%0D%0A%0D%0A"
        + text
        + "%0D%0A%0D%0AMit%20freundlichen%20Gr\u00fc\u00dfen%0D%0A"
        + Login.vorname + "%20" + Login.nachname;

try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().mail(
            URI.create("mailto:" + mail + "?subject="
                    + ueberschrift + "&body=" + text));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outlook opens an email-Window with the right initiation and end (what i wrote in java), but the String `text` is completely wrong.
If I comment out the replace methods, it completely does not work.
On Linux it works well!

Sehr geehrte Frau XX,

Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consetetur%20sadipscing%20elitr,%20sed%20diam%20nonumy%20eirmod%20tempor%20invidunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliquyam%20erat,%20sed%20diam%20voluptua.%20At%20vero%20eos%20et%20accusam%20et%20justo%20duo%20dolores%20et%20ea%20rebum.%20Stet%20clita%20kasd%20gubergren,%20no%20sea%20takimata%20sanctus%20est%20Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet.%20Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consetetur%20sadipscing%20elitr,%20sed%20diam%20nonumy%20eirmod%20tempor%20invidunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliquyam%20erat,%20sed%20diam%20voluptua.%20At%20vero%20eos%20et%20accusam%20et%20justo%20duo%20dolores%20et%20ea%20rebum.%20Stet%20clita%20kasd%20gubergren,%20no%20sea%20takimata%20sanctus%20est%20Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet.

Mit freundlichen Grüßen
bla bla

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacements don't look right. You're doing:

```
text.replace(" ", "%20")
    .replace("\n", "%0D%0A")
    .replace("\"", "\u00A8")
    .replace("%", "%25")
    ; // and so on
```

If you have a space, in the first replacement, you replace it with `%20`. Then in the fourth replacement, you replace all your percentage signs with `%25`. For a space this will result in the following replacements:

`" "` → `"%20"` → `"%2520"`

This results in the output you're seeing. If you want to keep using your handcrafted URL encoding mechanism, replace the percentages first, and then the other characters.

It would however be easier to use something like Java's [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), or Guava's [`UrlEscapers`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html).